LINK 2005 error based on my own class that I did not double include. How to track down and resolve issue?
I am currently getting the following error:
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned char * fontArray" (?fontArray@@3PAEA) already defined in Chip8.obj    CHIP 8  C:\Users\Cyani\source\repos\CHIP-8\main.obj 1   

I understand that it is saying that I am double defining fontArray and that this is usually caused by including a header that has already been included through a different header.  The thing is, I can't seem to find where I did this.  fontArray is located in the Font.h file.
file.h:
#include <cstdint>

const unsigned int FONTSET_SIZE = 80;

uint8_t fontArray[FONTSET_SIZE] =
{
    0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, // 0
    0x20, 0x60, 0x20, 0x20, 0x70, // 1
    0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // 2
    0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 3
    0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0x10, // 4
    0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 5
    0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 6
    0xF0, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x40, // 7
    0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 8
    0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 9
    0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, // A
    0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, // B
    0xF0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xF0, // C
    0xE0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xE0, // D
    0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // E
    0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80  // F
};

and it is included in the Chip8.h header:
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include "Font.h"

class Chip8
{
public:
    uint8_t registers[16]{};
    uint8_t memory[4096]{};
    uint16_t index{};
    uint16_t pc{};
    uint16_t stack[16]{};
    uint16_t sp{};
    uint8_t delayTimer{};
    uint8_t soundTimer{};
    uint8_t keypad[16]{};
    uint32_t video[64 * 32]{};
    uint16_t opcode;


    Chip8() : randGen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()) {

        //init rng
        randByte = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 255);
        //init PC
        pc = START_ADDRESS;


        //load fonts into mem
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < FONTSET_SIZE; ++i) {
            memory[FONT_ADDRESS + i] = fontArray[i];
        }
        // Set up function pointer table
        table[0x0] = &Chip8::Table0;
        table[0x1] = &Chip8::OP_1nnn;
        table[0x2] = &Chip8::OP_2nnn;
        table[0x3] = &Chip8::OP_3xkk;
        table[0x4] = &Chip8::OP_4xkk;
        table[0x5] = &Chip8::OP_5xy0;
        table[0x6] = &Chip8::OP_6xkk;
        table[0x7] = &Chip8::OP_7xkk;
        table[0x8] = &Chip8::Table8;
        table[0x9] = &Chip8::OP_9xy0;
        table[0xA] = &Chip8::OP_Annn;
        table[0xB] = &Chip8::OP_Bnnn;
        table[0xC] = &Chip8::OP_Cxkk;
        table[0xD] = &Chip8::OP_Dxyn;
        table[0xE] = &Chip8::TableE;
        table[0xF] = &Chip8::TableF;
        ...

So my question is, am I looking in the wrong place?  Visual studio says its an issue in the Chip8.obj so I assume it's an issue in the Chip8.h header.

Use extern in the header and remove the initializer from the header and put the definition in source file.

Don't put data in a header file.  Every source file that includes the header file will get a copy of the data.

C++ extern array declared in header not usable in main.cpp
